# Upload/Download Files with Silvelright and Entity Framework

Tags: .net, silverlight, entity-framework, ria

I need a solution to Upload Files (of any type) using a Silvelright 4 client and using Entity Framework 4 to make the connection with the database. After the files are uploaded how can I download them from the server.
Additionally but not necessary would be cool to group some files and been able to download them in a ZIP file.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Where do you save files, in the file system with paths in the database or in the database using filestream? I want to ask it because I suppose you want not only  to send a file to a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with Silverlight 4, WCF RIA services and EF4.

You build a domainService that allows you to pass the uploaded file from the Silverlight client to the server. The domainService persists your file into a backend database.

Gaining access to the files that have been uploaded can be via the WCF RIA service domainService but accessing its SOAP endpoint or ODATA endpoint.

OR

You could expose the files using an ADO.NET Data Services project giving you more control on the ODATA endpoint, even including the file grouping and zipping.

Comment: Getting timeout error while calling domainservice file upload.. Getting error only more that 1 Mb files. I also added <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" requestLengthDiskThreshold="1048576" executionTimeout="1000" />